# Animate CC HTML5/Canvas controling a nested MovieClip timeline with actionscript

Tags: canvas, jquery-animate, createjs, cc

I have a problem i can't seem to wrap my head around.
In the Animate CC Canvas IDE I created a Movieclip with several frames and on each frame is another nested movieclip and ocasionally that also contains other movieclips (all with instance names while the mainMc is added via addChild() to the stage).

so "mainMc > subMc > subSubMc"

Now i try to control the timeline of the subMc, respectively the subSubMc

I figuered it would be easy as
mainMc.stop(); or
mainMc.gotoAndStop('label');
works like a charm.

If i try to control the timeline of a subMC like
mainMc.subMc.stop(); or any other timeline command absolutely nothing happens and the MC keeps looping.

The console doesn't throw any errors and it works absolutely fine if i try to do any other operations on a nested mc - like alpha, rotation, coordinates etc. Every property except "paused" seems to be responsive. I absolutely do not understand why ...

Why the heck can't i control the timeline of nested MovieClips/Symbols/Instances?
Help please? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to a bug where nested content is not immediately available. Usually as long as you call gotoAndStop/gotoAndPlay on the parent movieClip *first*, then the children should be available.

```
mainMc.gotoAndStop(0);
mainMc.subMc.stop(); // Might need gotoAndStop here for the next line to work...
mainMc.subMc.subSubMc.stop();
```

Currently, this is an issue that needs to be solved by Adobe (not CreateJS), so we are working on getting it solved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I actually tried this to no avail. What ultimately did work is this over 3 years ol tip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871538/html5-canvas-flash-how-to-access-children-movie-clip-and-make-it-gotoandplay?rq=1

Comment: I stand corrected. It does work! I just used mainMc.stop(); and didn't even think of using gotoAndStop(0)! That is so much better than using events. Thanks a lot for this awesome tip. This need to be publically known or better yet, fixed!

Comment: Yep, we would love to see it fixed too :)